# Which components of Android to use?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, frontend

I am trying to achieve the list of buttons for "account, privacy, security etc" like in the image. I have tried radio buttons so far but cant set their background color and they do not last from left side to right side. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Use recyclerview  example  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

You may use buttons, but you need to set the attribute android:layout_width="match_parent" for them to span the whole width of the activity.

```
<Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Account"/>
```